# McAfee installation in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 18.04, software-installation, directory, antivirus

I installed McAfee antivirus and entered product key also. After installation they asked serial number and I entered correctly. Then it showing that serial number is already exist.why?

Comment: have you looked at this resource? https://community.mcafee.com/t5/Mac-and-Linux-Products/Install-Mcafee-in-my-Ubuntu-PC/td-p/305491

Comment: You really don't need an antivirus in Ubuntu

Comment: Completely agree with ArchismanPanigrahi - if you adopt basic security tricks you just _don't need_ an antivirus. If you have security concerns, you might want to take a look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Security.